# Extract only desired columns from a website

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request

I've got this code, it scraps this data from imdb: top 250 movies, fields name, year and rating.. and I'm trying to figure out how to extract only the movies in which Brad Pitt is, I've searched a lot of similar questions, but none really helped, I appreciate any contribution coming from you!

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'http://www.imdb.com/chart/top'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

movies = soup.select('td.titleColumn')
links = [a.attrs.get('href') for a in soup.select('td.titleColumn a')]
crew = [a.attrs.get('title') for a in soup.select('td.titleColumn a')]
ratings = [b.attrs.get('data-value') for b in soup.select('td.posterColumn span[name=ir]')]
votes = [b.attrs.get('data-value') for b in soup.select('td.ratingColumn strong')]
imdb = []
for index in range(0, len(movies)):
    movie_string = movies[index].get_text()
    movie = (' '.join(movie_string.split()).replace('.', ''))
    movie_title = movie[len(str(index)) + 1:-7]
    year = re.search('\((.*?)\)', movie_string).group(1)
    place = movie[:len(str(index)) - (len(movie))]
    data = {"movie_title": movie_title,
            "year": year,
            "place": place,
            "star_cast": crew[index],
            "rating": ratings[index],
            "vote": votes[index],
            "link": links[index]}
    imdb.append(data)

for item in imdb:
    print(item['place'], '-', item['movie_title'], '(' + item['year'] + ') -', 'Starring:', item['star_cast'])
```

Comment: You should nbe able to solve that using simple if statements ... what did you try?

Comment: Beside that you can change the URI to see onlypit films: https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000093/videogallery?ref_=nm_phs_vi

Comment: Rather look for code examples, try debugging the code you have and see what the result at each step and compare it against what you would expect to see.

Comment: @PatrickArtner I am a beginner, i didn't know what to do, thank you for helping me out!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Post processing your idmb list you can do the following, to get all the results with `brad pitt` in `star_cast`:

```
for item in imdb:
    if item['star_cast'].find('Brad Pitt') !=-1:
        print(item['place'], '-', item['movie_title'], '(' + item['year'] + ') -', 'Starring:', item['star_cast'])
```

**Output**

```
11 - Fight Club (1999) - Starring: David Fincher (dir.), Brad Pitt, Edward Norton
20 - Sieben (1995) - Starring: David Fincher (dir.), Morgan Freeman, Brad Pitt
85 - Inglourious Basterds (2009) - Starring: Quentin Tarantino (dir.), Brad Pitt, Diane Kruger
105 - Snatch - Schweine und Diamanten (2000) - Starring: Guy Ritchie (dir.), Jason Statham, Brad Pitt
```